# Using twitter bootstrap to create sidebar in master-detail UI

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Using twitter bootstrap, I am trying to create a sidebar in a master-detail UI with the code below. The problem is that the sidebar is always appearing right above the main content or details section as shown in the image below. Any suggestions on fixing this will be helpful. thanks.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
       </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row-fluid">
     <ul class="nav nav-list span3 well pull-right">
      <li> <a href="#"> Home </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="/posts"> Post </a> </li>
     </ul>

    <div class="span9 well">

    </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

This is the only custom CSS used:

```
 body{padding: 60px 10px 10px 10px;}
```

[image]

**Solved**

What caused my problem was that, my <**div class="container-fluid"**> was not wrapped with an outer row class eg <**div class="row-fluid"**>. Once I did that, everything was fine.

Comment: Are you familiar with CTRL + PrtSc?

Comment: No Kevin, Is there something you want me to know about it. cheers.

Comment: If you hold control and hit prtsc it will take a screen capture, then you don't have to take a picture of your screen.  Simply open the a paint program and paste in the captured screen shot.

Comment: lol never seen someone do this before on SO

Comment: Yes, though i just click print screen key on my PC without using CTRL.

Comment: Had to take a shot because my Linux is slow if I want to log into Stackoverflow. It is a guest OS. Took the shot, then logged out switched to windows and uploaded it here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7MD6m/ I just created this with bootstrap CSS attached - there must be other code affecting your layout as this seems fine?

Comment: @adaam The class attribute on the `ul` is missing a closing quote

Comment: adaam thanks. I will log back into my linux and find out what is interfering with the code. Many thanks.

Comment: @brg Checkout that closing quote

Comment: @KevinBowersox Yes just noticed this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as Kevin's fix:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list span3 well pull-right">
```

Based on the unknown that you might have other code effecting the width of the divs causing them to sit on top of each other use a lower span number to compensate like this (span numbers must add up to the Bootstrap maximum of 12 i.e. 9 + 3 in your code above [under normal circumstances would work]):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
       </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row-fluid">
     <ul class="nav nav-list span3 well pull-right">
      <li> <a href="#"> Home </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="/posts"> Post </a> </li>
     </ul>

    <div class="span8 well">

    </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

Wouldn't usually advise this as it's not **strictly** correct but as this is just for a backend page it seems it will be O.K. So here's a jsFiddle (bit hacky but oh well): http://jsfiddle.net/7MD6m/

Answer (score 2):

Your missing a closing quote here:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list span3 well pull-right>
```

Comment: Thanks kevin, that's is a typo from my end why typing into stackoverflow. On the the Linux dev server, I had checked all the tags and quote before logging out and they were fine.

Answer (score 2):

Twitter Bootstrap now provides [examples](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples), which contain a [Master/Detail template](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/fluid.html). There's no need for `pull-right` or the the quote hack. Here's adaam's example with the hack removed, working perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/2Zy6D/

Comment: Thanks, I will upvote you, though the problem has long been resolved without using **pull-right**. What caused my problem was that, my **<div class="container-fluid">** was not wrapped with an outer row class eg **<div class="row-fluid">**. Once I did that, everything was fine and I didn't use **pull-right**. I didn't post back my solution but now with this comment, I have added it.

Comment: I do believe that **containers** are meant to wrap **rows**, not vise-versa. **Rows** are for wrapping **spans**.

Comment: I am referring to whatever section of your code wraps the side bar in a master detail layout. I changed your jsfiddle to show what I mean: **http://jsfiddle.net/2Zy6D/1/**. I placed **<ul class="nav nav-list well span3">** without wrapping it in **rows**.

Comment: Oh I see. I was simply correcting the issue the OP was about (to prove a point), I didn't bother fixing the structure of his/her HTML.